# What is the fastest way to count all non-zero bytes of a byte slice

Tags: performance, go

I have a byte slice like this:

```golang
mbBytes := 1048576
x := make([]byte, 16 * mbBytes)
```

I'm aware of `bytes.Trim(s []byte, cutset string)` method that let us slice off all leading and trailing `cutset` occurrences, but it seems like this method is pretty slow – it takes roughly 80ms to remove all zeros from such slice.

I tried the alternate approach below;

```golang
func nonZeroLength(b []byte) int {
    a := 0
    for _, v := range b {
        if v != 0 {
            a++
        }
    }
    return a
}
```

This method is somewhat 8-10x faster than `bytes.Trim()`.

But when slice is filled with a lot of non-zero values – these methods are pretty slow.

Is there any faster algorithm or built-in methods to remove zeros from a byte slice?

Comment: The data you're filling it with will never contain a zero, then? (Also, how did you manage to fill it in a way that lost the number of bytes written?)

Comment: "By default len(slice) will return slice's max capacity and it doesn't show how much space is already taken in a slice." Not true. `cap(slice)` returns its capacity, `len(slice)` returns its length. Also "its true size" includes the zeros - the byte `0` takes up exactly one byte, the same as any other byte value.

Comment: Note that `make([]byte, n)` makes a byte slice with length `n`. Perhaps you wanted `make([]byte, 0, n)`—a slice with length zero, but initial capacity `n`.

Comment: I have an idea why this Q was downvoted (it's not asking to fix a "problem", I suppose), but it actually resulted in a useful and interesting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other's pointed out "its true size" and "count all non-zero bytes" are different things, but I'll leave that as terminology.

A fast way to count all non-zero bytes is to use [bytes.Count](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Count) to count the zero bytes and subtract that from the length of the array.

```
non_zero_count = len(x) - bytes.Count(x, []byte("\x00"))
```

This is about 10x faster than your function.